# How to use already existing object by hash number

Tags: java

Code should check whether there is circle with the same radius if so return already existing circle. Radius is the key. I don't want to create new Circle but use already existing one.

```
  public Circle buildCircle(int radius) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Circle> circleEntry : circles.entrySet())
        if (circleEntry.getKey() == radius) {
            return circleEntry.getValue();
        }
//if circle with given radius doesn't exist create that circle

    Circle put = new Circle(radius);
    return put;
}
```

I checked that witch bugger and hash number is different.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ShapeService shapeService = new ShapeService();

    Circle c1 = shapeService.buildCircle(5);
    Circle c2 = shapeService.buildCircle(5);


 if (c1.equals(c2)) {
        System.out.println("the same");
```

Something is wrong with `Circle put = new Circle(radius)` I guess.

Comment: "Same radius" isn't the same as a hash number.  I'd make the radius part of an `equals()` check.  In other words, you just have a standard check if two objects are the same, nothing special.  Try it that way, without the hash number, see if it works the way you want.

Comment: You can use a HashSet to store Cirlce objects.  Ensure the equals and hashcode method of the Circle class take radius as equality parameter.

Comment: Circle put is correct? It is the right way to put sth. on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the created object into the map in case of a "cache miss". So the cache-map just stays empty:

```
Circle put = new Circle(radius);
circles.put(radius, put); // This one was missing!
return put;
```

Since Java 8, you can use `Map.computeIfAbsent` to avoid the boilerplate code, and the whole method becomes a one-liner:

```
public Circle buildCircle(int radius) {
    return circles.computeIfAbsent(radius, Circle::new);
}
```